# html elements text/hidden along with file should be submitted?

Tags: html, file, text, input, hidden

how to submit html elements text, hidden etc., along with file element?

While using multipart for file element, the other elements are not read, like request.getParameter("") gives me null for other text/hidden elements...

please help me in this with the solution...

Thanks.
Narban.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your assumption is not true: Other form fields definitely get transmitted as well in a multipart form. Can you show the code of your form, and the server side code you are using to parse it with?

Answer (score 0):

`<form enctype="multipart/form-data"...` definitely does what you want.

Comment: He is already using `multipart/form-data`. His problem is that the other fields don't seem to be transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your other elements are inside the same form as your file input, and ensure that you have set the name attribute on all input elements you want to submit.

Comment: MultipartParser mp; try { mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); Part part; while ((part = mp.readNextPart()) != null) { String name = part.getName(); if (part.isParam()) { // it's a parameter part ParamPart paramPart = (ParamPart) part; String value = paramPart.getStringValue(); System.out.println("param; name=" + name + ", value=" + value); } } } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }

i could get all elements with this...thanks...